# ¿Por que obtengo el siguiente error en la instalación de SQL Server Management Studio Express 2014?

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Al intentar instalar  SQL Server Management Studio express 2014 me muestra el siguiente error "Hay errores de validación en esta pagina.Haga clic en Aceptar para cerrar este cuadro de dialogo.
Revise los errores que se indican al final de la pagina de instalación y proporcione parámetros validos
o haga clic en Ayuda para obtener mas información" al momento de dar click en siguiente en la selección de características

Comment: Tu pregunta quedó incompleta, ¿no?

Comment: Creo que deberias añadir la imagen que esta dandote. ¿Revisaste los errores que te marca?

Comment: Como añado una imagen aca eso no lo se